# Creating a for loop using list of specific pairs of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, multi-index

I have a large data frame with many columns. I am trying to write a for loop that will do a couple of simple calculations between columns, but the columns must be specific, and I am identifying them based on location in the data frame. For example, I want to do the calculation between Column 8 and Column 1, between Column 8 and Column 7, etc.

What is the best way to create a list of the operations to be done, and call upon that list in a for loop?

I have this so far (just doing the operation manually, repeating a lot of code):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [[99,3,12,4,63,55,67,32,15,102,87,34,82,102,99,30,99,1]]

cols_m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1. FY21','2. FY22','3. FY23','4. FY24','5. FY25','6. FY26','7. FY27','8. FY28','9. FY29'],['Values','Sites']])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols_m)

cols = df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()

first_col = df.xs(cols[1], level=0, axis=1)
second_col = df.xs(cols[8], level=0, axis=1)
d = second_col - first_col
e = (second_col/first_col - 1) * 100
d = pd.concat({f"{cols[8]}-{cols[1]}": d}, axis=1)
e = pd.concat({f"{cols[8]}-{cols[1]} %Change": e}, axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, d, e], axis=1)



del first_col, second_col, d, e
first_col = df.xs(cols[7], level=0, axis=1)
second_col = df.xs(cols[8], level=0, axis=1)
d = second_col - first_col
e = (second_col/first_col - 1) * 100
d = pd.concat({f"{cols[8]}-{cols[7]}": d}, axis=1)
e = pd.concat({f"{cols[8]}-{cols[7]} %Change": e}, axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, d, e], axis=1)

and on and on, with different columns inserted...
```

[image]

I would ideally like to have something like below (same output), but I am not sure how to create the list:

```
list = {col[8] - col[1], col[8] - col[7]}   #etc. etc. 


all_dfs = []
for i, j in list: 
     first_col = df.xs(cols[i], level=0, axis=1)
     second_col = df.xs(cols[j], level=0, axis=1)
     d = second_col - first_col
     e = (second_col/first_col - 1) * 100
     d = pd.concat({f"{cols[j]}-{cols[i]}": d}, axis=1)
     e = pd.concat({f"{cols[j]}-{cols[i]} %Change": e}, axis=1)
     df = pd.concat([df, d, e], axis=1)
```

Comment: What is column.8? 8.FY28 or 9.FY29? What are columns 0 and 9?

Comment: @mozway They are the locations of the columns in the df. So column 0 is 1. FY21, column 1 is 2. FY22. Column 7 would be 8. FY28, and column 8 would be 9. FY29

Comment: OK, but then there is no column 9 ;)

Comment: yes, true. it's arbitrary which columns, it's just for the example. I'll update the description :)

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I understood correctly, see below if this works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of tuples:

```
pairs = [(8, 1), (8, 7)]

l = [df]
for i, j in pairs:
    first_col = df.xs(cols[j], level=0, axis=1)
    second_col = df.xs(cols[i], level=0, axis=1)
    d = second_col - first_col
    e = (second_col/first_col - 1) * 100
    l.append(pd.concat({f"{cols[i]}-{cols[j]}": d,
                        f"{cols[i]}-{cols[j]} %Change": e},
                      axis=1)
             )

out = pd.concat(l, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  1. FY21       2. FY22       3. FY23       4. FY24       5. FY25       6. FY26       7. FY27       8. FY28       9. FY29       9. FY29-2. FY22       9. FY29-2. FY22 %Change       9. FY29-2. FY22       9. FY29-2. FY22 %Change       9. FY29-8. FY28       9. FY29-8. FY28 %Change           
   Values Sites  Values Sites  Values Sites  Values Sites  Values Sites  Values Sites  Values Sites  Values Sites  Values Sites          Values Sites                  Values Sites          Values Sites                  Values Sites          Values Sites                  Values      Sites
0      99     3      12     4      63    55      67    32      15   102      87    34      82   102      99    30      99     1              87    -3                   725.0 -75.0              87    -3                   725.0 -75.0               0   -29                     0.0 -96.666667
```